# Как безопасно добавить элементы в коллекцию при использовании итератора?

Tags: c#, коллекции, итераторы

В коллекцию постоянно добавляются сообщения об изменении в программе и мне нужно выводить эти изменения в textbox. Для этого использую метод Print, где получаю строку для вывода.

```
class Journal
{
    // Коллекция для событий
    private List<CollectionHandlerEventArgs> journal = new List<CollectionHandlerEventArgs>();

    // Добавить событие в коллекцию
    public void Add(string Name, string Type_of_Change)
    {
        journal.Add(new CollectionHandlerEventArgs(Name, Type_of_Change));
    }

    // Обработчик изменений на сервере
    public void ServerChanged(CollectionHandlerEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionHandlerEventArgs je = new CollectionHandlerEventArgs(e.Name, e.Type_of_Change);
        journal.Add(je);
    }

    // Обработчик изменений клиента
    public void ClientChanged(CollectionHandlerEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionHandlerEventArgs je = new CollectionHandlerEventArgs(e.Name, e.Type_of_Change);
        journal.Add(je);
    }

    // Получение строки с изменениями
    public string Print()
    {
        string s = null;
        foreach (CollectionHandlerEventArgs j in journal)
        {
            s += j.Name + ": " + j.Type_of_Change + "\n";
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

Нашел ошибку в том, что во время итерации нельзя изменять коллекцию, однако мне необходимо это сделать. Как исправить?

Comment: Спасибо за минус, но лучше бы подсказали что не так.

Comment: что есть `journal`?

Comment: @Igor коллекция, в которой каждый из элементов - это объект содержащий в себе сообщение об изменении в программе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка вызвана изменениями в списке в то время, когда существует энумератор этого списка. В цикле `for` никакого энумератора не создается.

```
for (int i = 0; i < journal.Count; i++) {
  CollectionHandlerEventArgs item = journal[i];
  s += item.Name + ": " + item.Type_of_Change + "\n";
}
```

Потоко-безопасный вариант:

```
private ConcurrentBag<CollectionHandlerEventArgs> journal = new ConcurrentBag<CollectionHandlerEventArgs>();

...

foreach (CollectionHandlerEventArgs j in journal.ToArray())
{
  s += j.Name + ": " + j.Type_of_Change + "\n";
}
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы объяснить разницу между этими циклами, почему for не вызовет ошибку?

Comment: @raspberry367, а почему должен? Геттер индексатора не проверяет "версию списка" (`version`)

Comment: @АндрейNOP Уже разобрался, благодарю.